# SQL Server CE throws an Incompatibility exception

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

My application is opened and is closed immediately. It gives this error:

> *The application is trying to load native components of version 5692 that are incompatible with ADO.NET provider of version 8080. Incompatible versions can lead to application instability and hence loading of SQL Server Compact has been aborted. Install the correct version of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details.*

What is the problem? Any helps would be appreciated...

I tried SQL Server CE 3.5, 3.5 sp2, 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the KB article mentioned in the error message?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974247

```
CAUSE 
Compact based applications generally program against the Compact ADO.NET provider
(System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll). This provider in-turn communicates with the
native Compact components. In order to avoid various inconsistencies, a Compact 
ADO.NET provider of a certain version can talk only to the Compact native 
components of the same version. The following are some sample scenarios where 
this policy will be broken, and that will result in one of the previously 
mentioned two exceptions:
```

```
Resolution
At any given point of time, the correct state of a 64-bit computer, for SQL 
Server Compact, would be the following:

    Both x86 and amd64 MSIs are installed.
    Both x86 and amd64 MSIs are of the same version.

Therefore, if you face any similar issues, make sure that the computer has both 
x86 and amd64 MSIs of Compact are installed and they are of the same version. 
In case, they are not, then install Compact SP2 x86 and x64 MSIs from following 
link as needed:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E497988A-C93A-404C-B161-3A0B323DCE24&displaylang=en
```

Comment: Good answer, They were installed both x86 and x64. But I'm not sure that these make problem. Now I'm looking at article and do your tips.

Comment: @Mesut - If it helped you, please consider marking it as the answer. This helps other SO users who might stumble across the question to see there is a working solution to the issue. The same would apply to your other questions, by the way.